# Bigdecimal not giving results after decimal points

Tags: java

I have the following method to calculation percentage

```
    public static BigDecimal getPercentageSave(BigDecimal totalCostAfterSale, BigDecimal totalCostBeforeSale) {
        BigDecimal save = totalCostBeforeSale.subtract(totalCostAfterSale);
        if (save.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
            return BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }
        return (save.divide(totalCostBeforeSale, 2, RoundingMode.DOWN)).multiply(new BigDecimal(100));
    }
```

> But it only gives me results like xx.00  Eg. 56.00, 78.00

How can i get the something like `56.21` or `78.01`

Comment: Rounding a number to 2 decimal digits and then multiplying it by 100 yields something like xx.00. You may have more luck when you keep 4 decimals.

Comment: @Henry Actually i thought to remove the rounding but than i saw method deprecated and new method needs rounding. Is there any method which can avoid rounding ?

Comment: In general, you cannot avoid rounding. Take 1/7 for example.

Comment: @Henry Correct. Okay i will try with 4 decimals.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is in first rounding before multiplying by 100. Instead, you can multiply by 100 first, then divide with a precision of 2 after the multiplication like this:

```
return (save.multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).divide(totalCostBeforeSale, 2, RoundingMode.DOWN));
```